# Simple import statements for npm package

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-publish

I want to publish new [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) TypeScript package and I want to be able to use simple import statements (import multiple classes from library via single line) in my project e.g.:

```
import { FirstClass, SecondClass } from "my-repo";
```

At this time I have to use many longer import statements e.g.:

```
import { FirstClass} from "my-repo/first-class";
import { SecondClass } from "my-repo/second-class";
```

In the beginning, I have built the package with `tsc -p .` to dist and then run `npm publish`. Now I am experimenting with [pikapkg/pack](https://github.com/pikapkg/pack) to make the build process easier, however I still have to use the long import statements.

**Is there any tool to automatically create a package with a single file to import from (index.ts which is places as main in package.json) or have I to manually create main index.ts with all classes exported and each time I will add a new class add it also to index.ts again?**

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches to do this.

**Installing in `node_modules`**

In this case we want to install the library in the `node_modules` of the consumer and use `Node module resolution`.

The `Node module resolution` configuration means, that the TypeScript compiler looks for the `node_modules` directory in your workspace and if there is an exported code in it which matches your import statement then it will be able to resolve it with the short import statement. You can find details about this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node).

If you have your library published and deployed in a registry (for example to https://registry.npmjs.org/ or in an Artifactory repository etc.) then add the deployed library to the `package.json` of the consumer as dependency and install it with `npm install`. With this step, the library will be installed in `node_modules` and if in the `tsconfig.json` you have in the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `Node module resolution` configured then the TypesSript compiler will be able to resolve the short import statement.

This approach assumes that you have the library deployed into a registry. If you have your library only local, then the CLI of [install-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-local) can help you to install the library in `node_modules` locally without any deployment. But there is an alternative to this, see therefore the next section.

**Referencing the published source directly from `dist`**

In the `tsconfig.json` of the consumer project you can specify your locally published modules in the `paths` of the `compilerOptions`settings (see details [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)). This way the TypeScript compiler will resolve the dependencies from the configured paths as well. It follows you don't need to install your dependency in the `node_modules` to use the short import statement, the compiler will find them following the configured paths.

Let's say I have a library called `my-lib`. The `dist` folder looks following:

```
dist
-->my-lib
---->{all the published files of my-lib}
-->my-app
---->{all the published files of my-app}
```

In this case an example `tsconfig.json` of the consumer looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "my-lib": [
        "dist/my-lib"
      ],
      "my-lib/*": [
        "dist/my-lib/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Above in the `paths` both `my-lib` and `my-lib/*` are needed. `my-lib` is what can be used in the short import statement, for example this way:

```
import { MyLibModule } from 'my-lib';
```

The paths after those entries in the tsconfig point to the published library in `dist`.

As far as I know the exports have to be done manually in the `index.ts` of the package.

Comment: And how can I automatically create index.ts (main in package.json) in my library which exports all my library classes from a subfolder? I want to do import { MyLibFirstClass, MyLibSecondClass } from 'my-lib';

Comment: As far as I know the exports have to be done manually in the `index.ts` of the package. I don't know any automation tool for this.

Comment: That's what I am looking for, because it's boring to add each class as export to index.ts again and again. However, thank you very much for your answer, it helped me to clarify some facts.